# Sort table when new data is entered in D, but follow this entry to new position

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I've a basic code for sorting an excel table, and it works well:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("C3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

However, its a hassle to find the entry in a large table when data is entered in C. Would it be possible to follow the record to its new position when it is sorted? If yes, how can I correct the code to do so?

Thank you!

Comment: One idea is to create a column with a dummy index (1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 etc..).
When you sort the order, the dummy column will be in the sorted order.  For example: (1,4, 2, 3, 5)

Comment: Sorry I don;t get what you mean. Did you mean that you want the new entry on column D also include the sorted range ? Is it a date that you sort only on column C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of way to do it. One of them is presented below.

Instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange()`, the following solution use `Worksheet_Change()`. The idea is to store the newly added value (the followings assumes u to type in column C directly to add new value. If you have a specific location in column D, change the `if` condition to check for change at that location.) and then search for it after sorting. It will scroll to the newly added value after sorting every time a new value is added. You may adjust to fit your usage.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim val As Variant
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        val = Target.Value

        Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=Range("C3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(val, Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)), 0) + 2
    End If
End Sub
```